# Unable to solve "A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization" exception

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net

We are moving from .NET native serialization to protobuf-net. Right now we are stuck trying to "un-graph" a complex data structure as we are getting an exception "A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization". I understand that we need to keep refactoring the involved classes but I'm unable to grasp the debugging information.

My edited stack trace:

```
en ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options)
en proto_6(Object , ProtoReader )
en proto_14(Object , ProtoReader )
en proto_12(Object , ProtoReader )
en proto_6(Object , ProtoReader )
en proto_4(Object , ProtoReader )
en proto_2(Object , ProtoReader )
en My.BlobManager.deserialize(Byte[] buffer)
en My.BlobManager.Load(String guid)
```

I assume that "proto_N" refers to a tagged attribute, right? Are those numbers the same as the tags? Any advise on how to debug this would be welcome.
Regards,
H.

Comment: You shouldn't see that error; that probably means something horrible happened in the serializer itself. Is there any way you can share any kind of repro for this? (not necessarily here on stackoverflow). It is hard for me to diagnose this without a repro.

Comment: What we are serializing consists of 5 classes, 150 fields, 10 collections (List<> and Dictionary<>).

Comment: believe it or not, that isn't very helpful in terms of reproducing it... what *would* be helpful is a minimal repro that demonstrates it. There are a myriad of ways I could layout 5 classes 150 fields and 10 collections / dictionaries.

Comment: I know! I was editing and hit intro. Here is my full reply: What we are serializing consists of 5 classes, 150 fields, 10 collections (List<> and Dictionary<>). AFAICT, there are cycles in this data structure and I'd rather refactor it to avoid them. I understand the any bug in your library would be impossible for you to solve it with the info I've provided. For me it would be enough if I could have some guidelines to detect which chain of objects were involved. Is that possible?

Comment: not really, unless "pare the model down until it stops, then add stuff back until it breaks".

Comment: Being doing that (tagging with ProtoIgnore), yesterday, and I think I've found the problem. Doesn't seem to be in the lib but in the way I was using the AsReference tag.